# How to display correct configured product image in cart page according to selected option?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want that when i click on add to cart button on product default page, The same image is shown on cart page according the selected color option of configurable product.

I tried below option from back-end but could not solve my problem,

```
System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart
```

and then set Configurable Product Image to Product Thumbnail Itself.

Is there any other way to do the same. ?